# how to read the variable value in the statement in python

Tags: python, syntax, format

`data = alice.get_instrument_by_symbol(Exchange, EMA)` in this command `Exchange` and `EMA` both are able to read the data from varialble.

but in the below command
`data = alice.get_instrument_for_fno(symbol = 'BANKNIFTY', expiry_date=datetime.date(2020, 10, 29), is_fut=False, strike=23200, is_CE = True)` ---- working

`data = alice.get_instrument_for_fno(symbol = 'Exchange', expiry_date=datetime.date(2020, 10, 29), is_fut=False, strike=23200, is_CE = True)` ---- not working ------

if i try to pass the same variable(Excahnge) it is not recognizing it.

looks like i am making some format issue in the python. requesting for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example (`data = alice.get_instrument_by_symbol(Exchange, EMA)`), `Exchange` and `EMA` are variables. The Python interpreter replaces them with their values at runtime (i.e. if `Exchange = 'BANKNIFTY'` is somewhere previous, `EXCHANGE` will be replaced with `BANKNIFTY`).

In the second example, the `symbol` keyword argument is getting passed in as a "string literal", meaning you explicitly say `'BANKNIFTY'`.

In the third example, you want to still use the `Exchange` variable (from the first example) as the `symbol` keyword argument to `get_instrument_for_fno`:

```
data = alice.get_instrument_for_fno(
    symbol = Exchange,  # Notice the lack of quotes
    expiry_date = datetime.date(2020, 10, 29),
    is_fut = False,
    strike = 23200,
    is_CE = True,
)
```

Comment: in my case i need to pass the value from the text file   in the below code i need to pass the all the value using reading the text file, (  Exchange , datetime.date(2020, 10, 29) , 23200) this all value should be read from the text( variable) currently it is not able to reading use below code also. so required help to fix this issue                                                            data = alice.get_instrument_for_fno(
    symbol = Exchange,  # Notice the lack of quotes
    expiry_date = datetime.date(2020, 10, 29),
    is_fut = False,
    strike = 23200,
    is_CE = True,
)